Construct CMC hypersurface from CMC codimension $2$ submanifold
Say we have an isometric immersion $P^{n-2} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with mean curvature vector $\vec{H}$.
Assume $P$ has constant mean curvature, meaning $|\vec{H}|^2=\text{constant}$ on $P$. And let's say it has flat normal bundle and parallel mean curvature vector too.
Is there a way to somehow "extend" $P^{n-2}$ to a hypersurface $M^{n-1}$ such that $M^{n-1}$ is CMC in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?
For example, by a result concerning reduction of codimension, if the first normal bundle has rank $1$, then $P$ lies in some hyperplane $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, and therefore we can just take the Riemannian product $P \times \mathbb{R}$, which is as CMC hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I am wondering if there is a more general way of doing such construction.
